# C# calling form.show() from another thread is not working in setup

Tags: c#, multithreading

In my c# windows application, I want to show another form on a condition which is checked by a thread. and that (second) thread is already called by another (first) thread. Here is the code I am using for more better explaination:

Main method:

```
static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
```

Form1 methods:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        // Call First thread to start background jobs.
        var thread = new Thread(ThreadFirst);
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();

        // Continue my load event stuff here...

}
    private void ThreadFirst()
    {
        // Do some background operations..
        // Call second thread to switch to another background process.
        var thread = new Thread(ThreadSecond);
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
}

private void ThreadSecond()
{
        If (condition)
                // navigate to another form and close running one..
                ShowAnotherForm();
        else
        {
                // Continue working on current form.
        }
}

[STAThread]
private void ShowAnotherForm()
{
     try
     {
           // Object for new form.
           globalForm = new myForm();
           globalForm.Show();
           // Close the current form running..
           this.Close();
           this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
           Application.Run();           
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
           messagebox.Show(ex.message);
     }
}
```

It is working perfect when I am running this from my solution. But, when I am creating a msi package for this, both of the forms got hide. Am I missing something to add into it so that it will work fine from setup also?

Thanks.

Comment: What does the call to Close() do there?

Comment: Close() is for closing the first form after displaying second one. I tried this.Hide() but doesn't work.

Comment: I think your problem is your a little bit off on the wrong track - if you can update your question to explain exactly what you are trying to accomplish with your code (give a little background and the result you desire) I think you can get a better answer

Comment: I hope it is better explained now. Please ask if anything else require to know.

Comment: Could you include your program's entry point? (i.e. Main method)

Comment: Aaron I have already included a scenario of my page load event (see the top). I am creating windows application not console. :)

Comment: Winforms applications have entry points.  If this is a windows store app, then I apologize for trying to help - they are not my area

Comment: No, you're right actually. Apology for not to understand your point..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling "GUI Stuff" on "Non GUI" threads.  All your GUI calls should be on the GUI thread. Use `InvokeRequired` and `Invoke` to ensure all your GUI code is done on the correct thread. Google will give you plenty of examples.